# Context based teaching

Tags: computer-science, teaching, university, lecture-teaching-method, information-technology

In areas such as information and computer science, what is meant by teaching in different contexts?  I have noticed some teaching positions require a document detailing contexts one has taught in. I have been searching on this topic and have found examples such as [this one](https://web.media.mit.edu/%7Elieber/Teaching/Context/Context-Intro/Context-Intro-bis/sld001.htm) , but I doubt this is what universities require. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the exemplar you refer to is not what they want.

---

Generally speaking, teaching context is your reflective approach.

> *In areas such as information and computer science, what is meant by teaching in different contexts?*

Just as you have *context* in information systems research, it is so in teaching. Essentially, what is/are the context(s) under which your teaching took place and how do you go engaging within those context.

Context covers the nuances, sociotechnical, structures, agencies, mechanisms beyond just demographics or description.
In IS, (IT, CS) teaching context goes beyond mere introducing and using '*technology*'.
With technology enhanced learning (edtech), teaching context would also speak to

- rationale for introducing the *platform*
- how the *platform* was dynamically engaged from a scholarship of teaching, learning and assessment
- what interventions took place for learners learning: learning outcomes, equity & diversity, learning experience...

Context implies reflexivity, the research-based teaching.

---

A thought from [PennState](http://www.personal.psu.edu/dgm122/docs/EDUC591_context.doc).

Some literature '*context*' on teaching contexts

- [book chapter on understand teaching context](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/practice-teaching/understanding-the-teaching-context/A7AFE13E31C260DED7CB5C72E81FB632)
- [article towards supporting well-being](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0309877X.2021.2023733)
- [approach to teaching](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03075070600680539)

Answer (score 3):

Teaching in different contexts often means teaching in different ways using different methods and different situations. All these differences are combined into the covering phrase "contexts".

It is asking you to explain if you have taught in a large lecture room, a small group tutorial, in a laboratory practical, one-to-one support tutorial, pre-recorded video and how you changed your approach for the different situations. They want to measure your teaching experience and approach against other candidates.